# Black Hole Collision

Tags: black-holes, collision

What would happen if two equally massive black holes directly collided at 5% the speed of light. I'm not talking about slowly orbiting each other for thousand of years. I mean one instant catastrophic event as with a hadron collider. Could the energy be enough to blast all matter (from the black holes) into a huge cloud that would then form into a galaxy and slowly back to another black hole?  There are similar questions but I am particularly interested in the possibility that this could happening at all considering most black hole theories say that once information goes in it can't come out.

Comment: Yes I read that but it did not seem that event was quite as catastrophic.

Comment: Note that a massive object technically speaking doesn't have a speed-maximum, it has a speed-supremum, a.k.a. $c$.

Comment: When I said Pius be physically possible I just met an average of what might be excepted from everyone else discussing this. I would think the minimum speed could be equivalent to the fastest thing we've ever observed moving in the universe.

Comment: Could someone remove the "marked as duplication" considering I am asking a different question. Thanks